# LINQ OrderBy only on second property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like

```
| column1 | column2 |
|    1    |   72    |
|    2    |   30    |
|    3    |   27    |
|    3    |   38    |
|    4    |   72    |
```

As you can see, the list is already sorted on column1, my goal here is to perform an OrderByDescending on the second column only on equals columns 1. Basically, I want

```
| column1 | column2 |
|    1    |   72    |
|    2    |   30    |
|    3    |   38    |
|    3    |   27    |
|    4    |   72    |
```

I can't re-run the first OrderBy (that'll be hard to explain, we don't care, I just cant :D) so forget about
`list.OrderBy(e => e.column1).ThenByDescending(e => e.column2)`

In fact, I wouldn't have any problem if I could simply do a `.ThenByDescending(e => e.column2)` without having to do the `.OrderBy` (maybe I can run an "empty" `OrderBy` that won't change the sort ? Then I would be able to do the `ThenByDescending` ?)

Comment: What? You cannot order on `column1` before sorting on `colum2`? I don´t know if I understand this, however I do not see any other solution. Anyway you do not "re-run" anything, the two statements are executed deferredly when needed.

Comment: If you cant do which is obvious solution then you have to do hard way....Copy all column2 value in new list and sort that list and merge new list and old list

Comment: You should explain why this is not an option since it's exactly the way to go.

Comment: Well, I tried to be simple here, but the object I'm dealing with is not a list with 2 columns, it's a query (`IQueryable`) containing objects. That query comes from a generic function that handle the sort based on a parameter. So when I have my query in front of me (after the call to the function), I don't know on which column it's sorted, I just have to manage the second sort.

Comment: Well, I assume I can look at the parameter which is sent to the function to re-run the first OrderBy, I would like to avoid this solution, but it seems like I will have to go this way

Comment: Can you give a column which has the sorting rank, so you can 'sort' on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.column1).SelectMany(i => i.OrderByDescending(g => g.column2))
```

Will work with many providers, but some may not preserve the ordering in the `GroupBy`. In such a case:

```
list.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.column1).SelectMany(i => i.OrderByDescending(g => g.column2))
```

Will work by forcing the operation into memory (where the ordering is preserved by `GroupBy`), though with the disadvantage of all subsequent operations being done in-memory rather than on a DB etc.

Answer (score 3):

`list.OrderBy(e => e.column1).ThenByDescending(e => e.column2)` is still the way to go.

The algorithm has to know it has to sort on `e.column1` first, no matter if it actually changes something or not. It has to know it only has to sort `e.column2` **within the subset of the first sorting statement**. You can't do that with 'just' sorting on `column2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really DO have a list rather then an IEnumerable, it is actually possible to do this using [the overload of `List.Sort()` which lets you specify a subset of items to sort, along with a comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you have to do is an O(N) traversal of the list to determine where each subgroup occurs according to the already-sorted column. Then sort each subgroup of more than one item according to the secondary sort column.

There's a small amount of fiddlyness involved with selecting the keys with which to identify the subgroups and the keys with which to sort the subgroups.

Here's the implementation:

```
public static void SortSubgroupsBy<T>
(
    List<T> items, 
    Func<T, T, bool> sortedColumnComparer,  // Used to compare the already-sorted column.
    Func<T, T, int>  unsortedColumnComparer // Used to compare the unsorted column.
)
{
    var unsortedComparer = Comparer<T>.Create(
        (x, y) => unsortedColumnComparer(x, y));

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; ++i)
    {
        int j = i + 1;

        while (j < items.Count && sortedColumnComparer(items[i], items[j]))
            ++j;

        if ((j - i) > 1)
            items.Sort(i, j-i, unsortedComparer);
    }
}
```

Here's a complete demonstration in a Console app:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Item
        {
            public Item(int column1, int column2)
            {
                Column1 = column1;
                Column2 = column2;
            }

            public int Column1;
            public int Column2;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"[{Column1}, {Column2}]";
            }
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                List<Item> items = new List<Item>
                {
                    new Item(1, 72),
                    new Item(2, 29),
                    new Item(2, 30),
                    new Item(3, 27),
                    new Item(3, 38),
                    new Item(3, 53),
                    new Item(4, 72),
                    new Item(4, 21),
                    new Item(4, 86),
                    new Item(4, 17),
                    new Item(5, 90)
                };

                SortSubgroupsBy(
                    items, 
                    (x, y) => x.Column1 == y.Column1, // Compare sorted column.
                    (x, y) => y.Column2 - x.Column2); // Compare unsorted column.

                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", items));
            }

            public static void SortSubgroupsBy<T>
            (
                List<T> items, 
                Func<T, T, bool> sortedColumnComparer,  // Used to compare the already-sorted column.
                Func<T, T, int>  unsortedColumnComparer // Used to compare the unsorted column.
            )
            {
                var unsortedComparer = Comparer<T>.Create(
                    (x, y) => unsortedColumnComparer(x, y));

                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; ++i)
                {
                    int j = i + 1;

                    while (j < items.Count && sortedColumnComparer(items[i], items[j]))
                        ++j;

                    if ((j - i) > 1)
                        items.Sort(i, j-i, unsortedComparer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```